# Building new Visual Basic Project with MSBuild targetting .NET 2.0

Tags: vb.net, compiler-construction, build, msbuild

I have no problem building my VB project in both VS 2010 and 2012 againt .NET 2.0.

However, the MSBuild refuses to build it because it does not like one VB language feature introduced in VS 2010 (it is "implicit line continuation" to be more specific).

I tried the following parameters for MSBuild (from .NET 3.5):

```
/p:TargetFrameworkVersion=2.0
/toolsversion:3.5
```

This does not build as the VB feature I use have been introduced in 4.0 tools.

So I changed toolsversion to 4.0 (and using MSBuild from .NET 4.0):

```
/p:TargetFrameworkVersion=2.0
/toolsversion:4.0
```

And now MSBuild complains about another thing:

```
C:\Users\Libor\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETFramework,Version=2.0.AssemblyAttributes.vb(6,24):
error BC30002: Type 'System.Runtime.Versioning.TargetFrameworkAttribute' is not defined.
[project.vbproj]
```

The only solution now for me is to open my project in VS 2008 and manually correct the code so it is compatible with all tools. But I hope MSBuild can be configured so it builds properly, as VS can build the project against .NET 2.0, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Similar question and answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2419585/target-specific-version-of-net-with-msbuild).  They key is going to be:

```
msbuild YourSolution.sln /tv:4.0 /p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v2.0
```

Comment: Writing "/p:TargetFrameworkVersion=2.0" instead of "/p:TargetFrameworkVersion=v2.0" did it! Funny that not using the 'v' letter did work on other projects of mine...